# How to put FontAwesome ico in "pseudo element" in styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm looking for a way to put FontAwesome Unicode to pseudo-element (`::before`, `::after`) for customizing my button. I've tried several ways, but it's not working

```
export const WriteButton = styled.button`
    position:relative;
    width:170px;
    height:50px;    
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background:transparent;
    border:1px solid #ececec;
    outline:none;
    font-size:14px;

    ::before{
        content: "/uf0";
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        font-size:30px;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;c
        
    }
`

export const WriteButtonIco = styled(Pen)`
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:20px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    color:#111;
    z-index:2;
`
```

Comment: did you tried !important

Comment: and please add your code not the screenshot of your code

Comment: I TRIED not working

Comment: There are a few errors in the values in your pseudo element setting. See https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements for how to use Fontawesome in pseudo elements.